# Trying to use the optional stopping theorem for a tricky probability problem.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

**The problem**

You have $0$ marbles in your bag. You have a randomly ordered line of $200$ people. $100$ of which are friends and as such will give you a marble when they pass you. $100$ are enemies and they will take one if there is not one to take they will kill you.

What is the probability you will live?

**A quick answer**

This is a textbook example of [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) and we are left with $\frac{1}{101} $

**Going further**

Notice this is *almost* a simple random walk (in terms of our bank balance of marbles). We bust if we reach the $-1$. However, it is not a martingale as the probability of moving up or down is not constantly $\frac{1}{2}$. Having said this , we find the same answer to the problem if it was just a SRW with busting at $-1$, which is indeed what happens in our original problem. Or reaching $100$. (not a necessary condition for living however). Why do we get an almost the same answer?

I noticed that we can perfectly figure out the probability of moving up or down using the current state, $X_n$ and time index, $n$. That is the expected change between steps is $\frac{-X_{n-1}}{201-n}$. Using this are we able to construct a martingale of our current position?

Comment: This is known as [Bertrand's ballot theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem).  In that link, note that you are looking at a variant in which ties are allowed (there is a paragraph on this case).